# Android Webview Disable Accessibility: Skip TopNav

Tags: android, kotlin

I am making a simple news webview in android. it works fine but I see this "Accessibility: Skip TopNav"
as picture below. How do I get rid of that?
[image]

I am not sure what to try as I didn't even know why the option shows up in the first place.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hello pls share activity and xml code with we.